# "Authentication Rejected" message from remote Mac computer

Tags: connection, teamviewer

I have tried connecting from different computers (Vista,XP & iphone 4) from which i use to connect remote mac computer but now get this message of "Authentication Rejected"  it does get connected rarely.
Any solution/suggestions please.